# Can I instanciate an object inside another class?

Tags: c++

I have a class `Fluid` that I want to instantiate to the class `Well` in my code. But when I call it through `Fluid fluid(/*parameters*/)` in the `Well` constructor, I cannot use that object in other methods of the class `Well`.

```cpp
class Fluid {
public:
    Fluid() {
        // constructor
    }
};

class Well {
public:
    Well() {
        Fluid fluid(/*parameters*/);
    }
};
    
int main() {
    Well well();
}
```

Comment: If you want to use it in more than one place you must save it as a property or pass it in as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you wanted to save it as a member variable

```
class Well{
public:
  Well() : fluid(...parameters) { }

  void SomeMethod();
private:
  Fluid fluid;
};
```

Then later you can access this member

```
void Well::SomeMethod()
{
    fluid.do_something();  // can use fluid now
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Well` must have `Fluid` type member for it to be available in other functions apart from the constructor.

```
class Well{
Fluid fluid;
public:
Well() : fluid( /* parameters */ )
{
}
};
```

Also, it helps if you post code which actually compiles.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have access by other functions of your `Well`, your `fluid` should be a member variable. Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Fluid{
public:
    Fluid(){}
    void splash() {std::cout << "splash" << std::endl;}

};

struct Well{
public:
    Well(): fluid(/*params*/) { }
    void get_water () { fluid.splash();};
private:
    Fluid fluid;
};


int main(){
    Well well;
    well.get_water();
}
```

Live demo: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1ba14j)